# How to fetch particular data in column from JSON with keys

Tags: json, sqlite, cordova

I am not sure how to fetch particular data in column from JSON with the help of keys. From ajax request i am getting data from the server but i want to store it in sqlite as the columns in server

```
$("#xxx").click(function()
{

    var e = $("#mob").val();
    var p = $("#key").val();
    myDB.transaction(function(transaction)
    {
        transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User_data (data)', [],
        function(tx, result)
        {
            navigator.notification.alert("table created");
        }, 
        function(error)
        {
            navigator.notification.alert("error, table exists");
        });
    });

    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "http://192.168.1.4/sms/android.php",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { type:'login', phone: e, name: p },
        ContentType: "application/json",
        success: function(response)
        {

            var valuesInArray = JSON.stringify(response);
            var user_data = JSON.parse(valuesInArray);
            for(var item in user_data.Users)
            {
                myDB.transaction(function(transaction)
                {
                    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO User_data (id,date_closed) VALUES (item.id,item.date_closed)', [],
                    function(tx, result)
                    {
                        navigator.notification.alert("data inserted");
                    }, 
                    function(error)
                    {
                        navigator.notification.alert("error, table exists");
                    });
                });
            }   
        },
        error: function(e)
        {

            alert('Got ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
});
```

here is the image of the data i am getting from the server
[DATA IN ALERT BOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM4K0.png)

here, i want to fetch each column in the database.
Thankx in advance.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=** user=** password=***");
if(isset($_GET['type']))
{
    if($_GET['type'] == "login")
    {
        $mobile = $_GET['phone'];
        $key = $_GET['name'];

        $query = "select * from crm_lead where phone='$mobile' and id='$key'";

        $result = pg_query($query);

        while($myrow = pg_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $recipes[]=$myrow;
        }

        $output = json_encode(array('Users' => $recipes));
        echo "'".$output."';";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "invalid";
}   
pg_close();
```

?>

Comment: take the values from keys like, user_data.id, user_data.date_closed,

Comment: Before you store data as columns you should create/alter table so it has those columns. Currently it is created with the only column `data` of `text` type. Do you know columns (names and types) to be stored at the table creation time? Then create table with proper columns list.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "http://182.70.240.81:82/sms/android.php",
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        data: { type: 'login', phone: 9770869868, name: 14 },
        ContentType: "application/json",
        success: function (response) {
            var simpleJson = JSON.parse(response);
            var shortName = 'db_test';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'Test Information';
            var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
            var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            db.transaction(function (txe) {
                txe.executeSql('DROP TABLE User_data');
                txe.executeSql('CREATE TABLE User_data(id INTEGER,date_closed TEXT)');
                db.transaction(function (txe1) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < simpleJson.Users.length; i++) {

                        txe1.executeSql('INSERT INTO User_data (id,date_closed) VALUES (' + simpleJson.Users[i].id + ',"' + simpleJson.Users[i].date_closed + '")', [],
                            function (tx, result) {
                                alert("data inserted");
                            },
                            function (error) {
                                alert("error, table exists");
                            });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Remove Single Qoutaion from your json:
[image: Remove Single Qoutaion from your json]

Comment: you can check it, here is the address to the server http://192.168.1.4/sms/android.php

Comment: you can use this : for(var item in user_data.Users) { tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DATABASE (id,date_closed) VALUES (item.id,item.date_closed)'); }

Comment: i really appriciate your help..but still its not working, is it working on your system ???

Comment: please send me code you use it , you send me a local server and me cannot test it on my system.

Comment: code updated above, use 9770869868 and 14 in textbox (#mob, #key)

Comment: in your code you have taken simpleJson, sop my question is will it work on ajax request

Comment: you can get json directly from response of ajax request , but if you dont recive this you can first check this by dhc app on chrome and then if your respone is ok then use this : response.Users

Comment: i tried that, but nothing happened, are you able to access the server database.

Comment: with the numbers provided .

Comment: send me your server code if its your own , i cant access this server . if you want i access it publish this page on online server and then send me.

Comment: try two text box with the id provided. on my other PC i can access the database..enter on ID #mob = 9770869868 and #key= 14 ..u will be able to access server

Comment: u can try this also http://192.168.1.4/sms/android.php?type=login&phone=9039447044&name=28

Comment: Do you use any vpn connection ? this ip not a public ip and i cant access it , if you can send me a correct and ip public of server .

Comment: your php code is ok , but i need check your code with javascript , if you can upload this with sample data on a host and send me a url.

Comment: can you tell me any other way to get data from server and store it in sqlite

Comment: for get data from server in javascript (cordova - phonegap) you should use a http client and get data from server as json or stream and etc. you can get data from server by ajax and your code is correct , but you dont get any data from server and should looking for this problem. some samples : [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/) [link](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/)

Comment: hey bro...now i have made the ip public now you can check this out from the server 182.70.240.81:82/sms/android.php

Comment: thankx alot, btw it is working on your side, can you store data in sqlite from server

Comment: remove semicolon from end of your json.

Comment: see answer code i use it and worked.if this code not worked for you , plz check your code in browser.

Comment: its working now..thankx alot..really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use the response object directly since it's already a Json object?

```
var users = response.Users;
for(var i=0; i < users.length;i++)
{    
    var id = users[i].id;
     //do something with id
}
```

Comment: this code says, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
"